# Implement tags in python statsd library?

Tags: python, statsd

I am trying to use the `tags` feature in statsD. But in [python statsD](https://statsd.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3/#) there is no feature for tags. But in the documentation they recommended [alternatives](https://statsd.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3/tags.html?highlight=tags#unsupported-tagging-metrics) to implement tags that is [statsd-tags](https://pypi.org/project/statsd-tags/).

I have installed both `statsd` and `statsd-tags` but still I cant able to make it work. Here is my implemented code:

```
import statsd
statsd_client = statsd.StatsClient(host="localhost", port=8125)
statsd_client.incr('triggered',20, tags=['production', 'fqdn': 'example.org']) ---> Unexpected Argument
print("Done")
```

The IDE is throwing unexpected argument error. Am i missing anything here ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are importing the version of the statsd library without the Tags argument in incr function. You might want to delete that version via pip. Since they use same import name.

Comment: Yeah i tried that. If i remove 'statsd` then its thowing error like this `Cannot find reference 'StatsClient' in 'imported module statsd' `.

Comment: hm, you are able to import the module successfully, correct?

Comment: Yeah didnt get any error when importing the modules.

Comment: ok there is a possibility that it has something to do with the statsd-tags library being last updated 5 years ago. It looks like the developer removed it from GitHub as well. If you really want to find out what you have downloaded, I suggest you take a look at the source code of the file and see if StatsClient class exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag as per Influx StatsD tag notation(no need to install statsd-tags)

```
import statsd
c = statsd.StatsClient('localhost', 8125)
c.incr(f'Gitesh_counter_with_tag, key1={randint(1, 10)}, key2={randint(1, 10)}')
```

Ref - [Influx StatsD](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-sending-statsd-metrics-to-telegraf-influxdb/#introducing-influx-statsd)

[statsd exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter)